# Updating matrices subplots in for loop not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I read a lot of answers here and tutorials, but I cannot get this code to work.
I have a figure with three subplots on one row. Each subplot shows a matrix. I wrote a for loop to update the visualization of the matrices with a different numpy array at every iteration.
The figure opens, shows an initial state, does not update and closes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import time
import numpy as np

cmap_veg_wat = cm.get_cmap("Greens").copy()
cmap_veg_wat.set_under('#409fff')

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, num=None, figsize=(10,10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
index = count()
ind = 0

MATR1 = np.load('erb.npy')
MATR2 = np.load('carv.npy')
MATR3 = np.load('vegwat.npy')

ax[0].imshow(MATR2, cmap='Reds')
ax[1].imshow(MATR1, cmap='Greens')
ax[2].imshow(MATR3, cmap=cmap_veg_wat, vmin=0)

for x in range(3):
    npErb = 'erb'+ str(x) + '.npy'
    npCarv = 'carv'+ str(x) + '.npy'
    npVW = 'vegwat'+ str(x) + '.npy'

    MATR1 = np.load(npErb)
    MAMTR2 = np.load(npCarv)
    MATR3 = np.load(npVW)

    x_time = np.load('xT.npy')
    y_erbpopulation = np.load('yE.npy')
    y_carvpopulation = np.load('yC.npy')
    y_vegdensity = np.load('yV.npy')

    
    ax[0].imshow(MATR2, cmap='Reds')
    ax[1].imshow(MATR1, cmap='Greens')
    ax[2].imshow(MATR3, cmap=cmap_veg__wat, vmin=0)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're making a manual simulation rather than using `FuncAnimation` from your previous question?

Comment: This part of the code would be to repeat the simulation with the data generated in real time during the FuncAnimation. I tried using FuncAnimation here too in my attempts, but I couldn't make it work either. I posted here the last thing I tried.

Comment: @HeleneLef Helene, when I composed my answer I was focused on "make it happen", so I mostly neglected your implementation. Tonight I'll approach again your question with the different perspective and (maybe) I will be able to point at the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, *mutatis mutandis*, this is what you want.

I'm sorry I cannot post the animation, but if you save my code to a script, e.g. `3matrices.py` and next execute it, `$ python3 3matrices.py`, then you'll see the animation unfold in front of you...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

cmaps = 'Reds Greens Blues'.split()
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=240)

plt.ion()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10,10), sharey='all',
                        dpi=80, edgecolor='k', linewidth=3)

for x in range(4):
    fig.suptitle(str(x+1))
    mx = np.arange(60).reshape(15, 4)*(x+1)
    for ax, cmap in zip(axs, cmaps):
        ax.imshow(mx, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    if x<3 : time.sleep(1.0)

input('Press Invio to exit')
```

Comment: @jared I was deliberate in my (pretended) use of `cat`,  because I want to make clear that if you `$ python3 script.py` you are going to see the animation unfolding.

Comment: I don't understand: why does this work and mine does not? it seems like the same structure.

Comment: @HeleneLef I started from your code, tried to stay as close as possible, and it works... honest I don't know why